# How to integrate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+5}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals, wolfram-alpha

How to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+5}}dx$$.

In my school life , I learnt how to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}}dx$$ or $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x+b}}dx$$.

To integrate these types of expressions , we generally used to rationalize these expressions and then we used to integrate this expressions. For e.g.- to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x+b}}dx$$, we used to multiply the numerator and the denominator by $(\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b})$. Therefore finally the above integral will become $$\int \frac{\sqrt{x-a}-\sqrt{x-b}}{a-b}dx$$. Now after this step , it becomes very easy to integrate the above expression.

Similarly to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}}dx$$, we have to multiply the numerator and denominator by $(\sqrt{x+a}+\sqrt{x+b})$ and the integral will become easy.

Suddenly yesterday , it came in my mind that how to integrate $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}+\sqrt{x+c}}dx$$, where $a,b,c$ are in A.P.(Arithmetic Progression)?

I don't think that the method of rationalization will work here. Also I noticed one important thing here that Wolfram Alpha is not showing any result for $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+5}}dx$$ but Wolfram Alpha is giving result for $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+5}}dx$$ and the value is around $0.59$. Please help me out with this integral.

It is a very tough integral for me.

Comment: wolfram alpha says it is a [monster](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%24%5Cint+%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B1%7D-%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B3%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B5%7D%7Ddx%24)

Comment: Note that $$(a+b+c)(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)=a^4+b^4+c^4-2a^2b^2-2a^2c^2-2b^2c^2.$$ Maybe this would help. Probably not, but maybe.

Comment: Please help me out with the full solution, because it's a very tough integral for me. I haven't even figured it out how to solve.

Comment: When I get an exercise about $f(x+1, x+3, x+5)$, I have the habit of replacing $x$ by $x-3$, so I get the same exercise about $f(x-2, x, x+2)$, and the $-2$ and $+2$ neutralising each other generally makes the whole exercise a lot easier. Don't forget that $d(x-3)=dx$. Have fun!

Comment: @pie ... in particular, it is an **elliptic integral** .... when rationalized, the integrand involves the square-root of a cubic.$$-{\frac {x}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}\sqrt {x+3}}-3\,{\frac {\sqrt {x+3}}{3
\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}}+{\frac {x}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}\sqrt {x+1}}+7\,{
\frac {\sqrt {x+1}}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}}+2\,{\frac {\sqrt {x+5}\sqrt 
{x+1}\sqrt {x+3}}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}}+{\frac {x}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11
}\sqrt {x+5}}-{\frac {1}{3\,{x}^{2}+18\,x+11}\sqrt {x+5}}
$$  All except one of these terms has elementary integral, but one term does not.

Comment: Which term doesn't have elementary integral?@GEdgar.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLUTION OUTLINE :**

Let middle term be $\sqrt{x+b}=y$
We get $x=y^2-b$

Substitute that in the other terms to get $\sqrt{y^2+a-b}$ & $\sqrt{y^2+c-b}$

We can Partially rationalize Denominator : multiply $y+[\sqrt{\square}-\sqrt{\blacksquare}]$ by $y-[\sqrt{\square}-\sqrt{\blacksquare}]$

Denominator will be $y^2-[\square-2\sqrt{{\square}{\blacksquare}}+\blacksquare]$

We can then rationalize the Denominator which includes Single $\sqrt{\cdot}$ term.

We will have Numerator in terms of $y^2$ & $\sqrt{\cdot}$ while Denominator will be in terms of $y^2$ & higher Powers.

Substitute $z=y^2$ & Integrate each "numerator term / Denominator terms" to get the whole Integral.
Over-all , $x=z-b$ , which will give Original Integral.

With wolfram , thanks to comment by user "pie" , we can see that it will be a Monster. It will be very large & cumbersome to write out.

Numerical Integration is not cumbersome , though we will get approximate values.